# Changing login icon of finger print

Tags: windows-7, authentication, fingerprint

Is it somehow possible to change the image that's beeing showed, when finger print authentication is enabled? I'm talking of [this](http://www.bdragon.com/lair/wp-content/uploads/logon-fingerprint-small.jpg) image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to edit the `BioCredProv.dll` in `C:\Windows\System32` or (`C:\Windows\System` if you just running a 32 bit OS).  You also need a resource editor software to be able to change the icon.  It has to be a bitmap file.

First you need to make a backup copy of the .dll and keep it somewhere safe just in case you mess things up.  Also copy another copy of the dll file to a differnt folder, ie documents, so you can edit it.  Use the resource editor to open the file and you should see two icons listed, one for when you are correct or it is waiting, and the other when the scan is bad. I replaced both with different icons, but you could replace them both with the same also.

After you have edited the copied version and saved it somewhere, you need to be able to boot your computer without loading windows.  The easiest is to stick in a Ubuntu CD and boot into the demo.  Then you can mount the windows partition/hard drive and copy the edited dll to where the original is, in `C:\Windows\System32`.  If you have done everything correct, when you reboot you will see the new icons you put into the dll file.  If you screwed up, windows will not boot at all and you will need to go back into Ubuntu and copy back the backed up dll file.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer, that's good to know now. I just removed the logon images from the login pane with editing a windows dll (not sure which one it was probably winlogon or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

You would want to open the .dll file(s) that contains the image in an icon editor such as [Greenfish Icon Editor](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Graphic/Graphic-Editors/Greenfish-Icon-Editor-Pro.shtml). I don't know which .dll files contain the icon, however.